# How do I tell my Jquery command line to add a delay after each command line

Tags: jquery, delay, wait

What I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
                // NL flag
    $(this).find("#topbar_nl").width('100%');
    $(this).find("#midbar_nl").width('100%');
    $(this).find("#botbar_nl").width('100%');
});
```

I need it to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
                // NL flag
    $(this).find("#topbar_nl").width('100%');(wait for 2 seconds then go to next command line)
    $(this).find("#midbar_nl").width('100%');(wait for 2 seconds then go to next command line)
    $(this).find("#botbar_nl").width('100%');(wait for 2 seconds then go to next command line)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this

```
var arr =["#topbar_nl", "#midbar_nl", "#botbar_nl"], index = 0;
setInterval(function(){ // use setInterval for the delay
   if(index < arr.length) {
      $(this).find(arr[count]).width('100%'); // do the work
   }  index++; // update the index
}, 2000) // of 2 seconds
```

Comment: Isn't there a more simple way to add a delay? i know that .delay() works once you have multiple actions within 1 command line. isn't there a way that I can do that or something that requires less code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method for this:

```
$(this).find("#topbar_nl").animate( { width: '100%' }, 2000, function() {
    $(this).find("#midbar_nl").animate( { width: '100%' }, 2000, function() {
        $(this).find("#botbar_nl").animate( { width: '100%' }, 2000 );
    });
});
```

Comment: While this would work, it would make the `width` animation last 2 seconds, which may not be what the OP desired.